# accessing values of a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
reply = {icon:[{name:whatever,url:logo1.png},{name:whatever,url:logo2.png}]}
```

how do i access logo1.png ?

I tried :

```
print reply[icon][url]
```

and it gives me a error:

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

**`EDIT:`**

Bear in mind sometimes my dictionary changes to this :

```
reply = {icon:{name:whatever,url:logo1.png}}
```

I need a general solution which will work for both kinds of dictionaries

**EDIT2:**
My solution was like this :

```
    try:
        icon = reply['icon']['url']
        print icon
    except Exception:
        icon = reply['icon'][0]['url']
        print ipshit,icon
```

This works but looks horrible. I was wondering if there was an easier way than this

Comment: There is no simple solution for both, because one has dictionaries as the values and the other has lists.  You would have to explicitly check whether the value is a list or a dict.  Better to make the values *always* be lists, even if only a list with one element.

Comment: Also, this should go into a class so you can make proper objects and access them like `icon.url`.

Comment: Why is it that "sometimes my dictionary changes to this"? Why not just have a list of values in both cases? Is this format out of your control?

Comment: @user2357112 yes the format is out of my control .. this is a reply from website .. which changes into two types of dictionaries mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
reply[icon][0][url]
```

If you know for sure all the different kinds of responses that you will get, you'll have to write a parser where you're explicitly checking if the values are lists or dicts.

You could try this if it is only the two possibilities that you've described:

```
def get_icon_url(reply):
    return reply['icon'][0]['url']\
    if type(reply['icon']) is list else reply['icon']['url']
```

Comment: this works for the first kind of dictionary but fails for the second kind (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

so in this case, icon is the key to a list, that has two dictionaries with two key / value pairs in each. Also, it looks like you might want want your keys to be strings (icon = 'icon', name='name').. but perhaps they are variables in which case disregard, i'm going to use strings below because it seems the most correct

so:

```
reply['icon'] # is equal to a list: []
reply['icon'][0] # is equal to a dictionary: {}
reply['icon'][0]['name'] # is equal to 'whatever'
reply['icon'][0]['url'] # is equal to 'logo1.png'
reply['icon'][1] # is equal to the second dictionary: {}
reply['icon'][1]['name'] # is equal to 'whatever'
reply['icon'][1]['url'] # is equal to 'logo2.png'
```

you can access elements of those inner dictionaries by either knowing how many items are in the list, and reference theme explicitly as done above, or you can iterating through them:

```
for picture_dict in reply['icon']:
    name = picture_dict['name'] # is equal to 'whatever' on both iterations
    url = picture_dict['url'] #is 'logo1.png' on first iteration, 'logo2.png' on second.
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not so different, but maybe it looks better (KeyError gives finer control):

```
icon_data = reply['icon']
try:
    icon = icon_data['url']
    print icon
except KeyError:
    icon = icon_data[0]['url']
    print ipshit,icon
```

or:

```
icon_data = reply['icon']
if isinstance(icon_data, list):
    icon_data = icon_data[0]
icon = icon_data['url']
```